# Locale is incompatible error in Postgresql 10 when replicating from Ubunu to Win 10

Tags: windows, postgresql-10, collation, locales

The locale available in my Ubuntu PG-10 DB is en_US.UTF-8. When doing PG_Basebackup to a PG-10 DB in Win-10, Psql failed to connect with error

> psql: FATAL:  database locale is incompatible with operating system
>   DETAIL:  The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "en_US.UTF-8", 
>   which is not recognized by setlocale(). HINT:  Recreate the database
>   with another locale or install the missing locale.

The locale available in Win10 are

```
                          List of databases
   Name    | Owner      | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | 
-----------+------------+----------+---------+-------+-
 postgres  | postgres   | UTF8     | en-US   | en-US |



                                           List of databases
   Name    | Owner    | Encoding |          Collate           |           Ctype            | 
-----------+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
```

But the above locale are not taking when doing the Basebackup. Any fix for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy a data directory (which is what pg_basebackup does) between two different operating systems. The missing locale is just one symptom. If you need to replicate between Linux and Windows use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html) – [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)

Answer (score 0):

try to set the locale manually by using this command

```
sudo localedef -f CP1252 -i en_US English_United
sudo localedef -f CP1252 -i en_US "English_United States.1252"
```

then restart your postgres db server

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, the fix was to install the `language-pack-en` apt package and then restart PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get working streaming replication having Primary on windows and standby on Ubuntu, the error was related to locale but after updating the postgresql.conf file with 'English_United States.iso1252' as locale everything started working.

before changing this value I had to run the following command to install the language pack but not sure if this locale was already there before installation as i didnt check !

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y language-pack-en
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this "localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8" and reboot.